# JAX-WS binding to existing Java classes problem

Tags: java, soap, glassfish, jax-ws

Asking and answering my own question here, because I had a dickens of a time finding this online:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl.freeze(JavaMethodImpl.java:367)
```

Trying to call a web service from inside Glassfish v3. Works fine from JDK1.6.0_21

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a mismatch between the java interfaces and the WSDL you are attempting to bind to. It is supposedly "fixed" in the next version, but right now it fails with a cryptic message. The difference between the JDK JWS client and the Glassfish is how strict they are. If you have a remote @WebMethod that returns void and doesn't throw a checked exception, you *have* to use the @Oneway annotation on that method in the interface.

Comment: Do you know how to hide this cryptic message? It's ok if it is written somewhere but not into my console :-)